# Preventing a double redirect with htaccess

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect

I'm trying to create a redirect in-between page of sorts, because the URL that I'm redirecting  TO includes more information than the URL I'm redirecting FROM. I'm using a short domain (hrci.me) with an htaccess file to redirect to the full domain (currently reachchallenges.infectionist.com). An example would be:

hrci.me/ch123

The path, ch123, includes the identifier that lets me know it's a challenge link (ch), and the 123 is the challenge ID. Each challenge has a title that I like to append to the end of the URL for SEO purposes. This example URL would redirect to:

reachchallenges.infectionist.com/challenge/123/Challenge+Title

The "Challenge+Title" part is stored in the database and needs to be retrieved by the challenge id, so I wrote a simple PHP script that does just that and then handles the redirect itself. My htaccess rule looks like this:

```
RewriteRule ^ch([0-9]{1,4})(/)?$ redirhandler.php?chid=$1 [L]
```

So the request to /ch123 should redirect to redirhandler.php?chid=123, which would get the title then redirect to the other domain at /challenge/123/Challenge+Title. The problem is, the short domain is set up to forward all incoming requests to the long domain, maintaining the original path (so hrci.me/something would redirect to reachchallenges.infectionist.com/something), and I'm finding that after the htaccess handles the rewrite to redirhandler.php, it then redirects that to reachchallenges.infectionist.com/redirhandler.php...

Basically, I need it to ignore any further redirects if the path is redirhandler.php, allowing the php script to handle the rest o the redirect. I'm thinking a RewriteCond is how I might do this, but I can't figure it out.

Comment: how is the short domain setup to redirect to the long domain? Is that in the htaccess file as well? If so can you add that to the question as that is an important piece of the puzzle.

Comment: Yes the short domain redirect is set up in the htaccess.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like your rule that forwards *all* incoming requests to the long domain is higher up in the .htaccess file than the more specific rule for /ch* requests. Try putting the more specific rule before the more general one.

Comment: The rule to redirect all requests is the last rule in the file, and all the other rules specify the [L] flag.

Comment: Maybe a rule to match redirhandler and explicitly do nothing?  You can do that with a  single hyphen as the substitution.

Comment: I figured it out. I added a RewriteCond to ignore the redirect if the request uri was redirhandler.php, it seems to have worked. Thanks for the help.